# Copy a text from excel and paste it in textbox and Click the link after Search

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have been struggling with Selenium and Sikuli right now .
Currently I am stuck at point where I have to take the values from Excel and search it in text box( text box is on webpage which is a secured site i.e. html elements are embeded and are not viewable on page source).
After I search, I will be a getting the results and if the results appear I will have to click on the link else quit and search for next value from excel.

Can anyone please help me with a solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what doesn't work? Do not expect to copy values from excel using Selenium, look up some ways of reading from a CSV file in Java to get started

Comment: Hi Steve.. I am using apache-poi to read data from excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be better for you to parse the excel file then validate the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) to read a cell value from excel, try this:

First, if you use maven, add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use this code to get string value from excel file:

```
public static String ReadExcel (String filename) throws InvalidFormatException {

    File excel = null;
    FileInputStream file = null;

    try {

        excel = new File("D:\\tmp\\" + filename + ".xls");
        file  = new FileInputStream(excel);

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                cell = cellIterator.next();

                if (!cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {


                    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {

                        // your method to find data on page with param cell.getStringCellValue()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (file != null && excel != null) {

            file.close();
            //excel.delete();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then call search method on each cell iteration which will compare values with what you need on page.

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Or you can put values into list, for example, and then work with the list.

Comment: Thanks Nikita but It didn't work.I have to filter excel column based on another column and then paste those filtered values on webpage.